# How to solve a circular dependency problem when installing python packages by building them with nix?

Tags: nix, nix-flake

I'm trying to install DocArray and Jina Hubble SDK using Nix, but I'm encountering a circular dependency issue. Specifically, I need to install DocArray to proceed with the installation of Jina Hubble SDK, but Jina Hubble SDK is a prerequisite for installing DocArray.

flake.nix

```
{  description = "Python environment with ollama";

 inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

 outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      
      #Define Python package jina-hubble-sdk
      jina-hubble-sdk = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "jina-hubble-sdk";
          version = "0.39.0";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "9021417794a6d3cf3fad8a880cf668a3a986b9d53d5be5fa391aae1767a5b9b0";
          };
          preConfigure = ''
            export HOME=$(mktemp -d)
          '';


          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            opentelemetry-instrumentation-grpc
            uvloop
            aiofiles
            websockets
            pep517
            pip
            requests
            aiohttp
            rich
            importlib-metadata
            filelock
            pathspec
            docker
            pyyaml
            python-jose
          ];
        };
      # # Define Python package jcloud
      jcloud = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "jcloud";
          version = "0.3";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "dc062c0454041562476032768fc48f426cc40b8e2323d9626377ff44b0d6f3d9";
          };

          preConfigure = ''
            export HOME=$(mktemp -d)
          '';

          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            pip
            rich
            aiohttp
            jina-hubble-sdk
            packaging
            pyyaml
            python-dotenv
            python-dateutil
            #python-dateutil
            #python-dotenv
            #pyyaml
            # Add any dependencies jcloud might have here
          ];
        };

      # Define Python package jina
      jina = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "jina";
          version = "3.24.0";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "91f7a6141f46884b87d011e64cbf053391d418289391c3c633b10f0c7942553b";
          };

          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            pip
            jcloud
            # Add any dependencies jina might have here
          ];
        };

      # Define Python package docarray
      docarray = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "docarray";
          version = "0.40.0";
          format = "pyproject";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "c3f3b88b7b6128c10308dddbd21650c9845e270da850cf6718cb1d3d867d5986";
          };

          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            numpy
            orjson
            pydantic
            rich
            types-requests
            typing-inspect
          ];
        };

      # Define Python package vectordb
      vectordb = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "vectordb";
          version = "0.0.21";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "3f4857ed3f26dc2384415f28851526037058008156719ca0cfc208a9a02d88e8";
          };

          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            pip
            setuptools
            docarray
            jina
          ];
        };

      # Define Python environment with necessary packages
      pythonEnv = pkgs:
        pkgs.python3.withPackages (ps:
          with ps; [
            langchain-community
            langchainplus-sdk
            langchain
            tiktoken
            docarray
            vectordb
            jina # Include jina in the environment
            jcloud # Include jcloud in the environment
          ]);
    in {
      devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = with pkgs; [
          curl
          ollama
          (pythonEnv pkgs)
        ];
      };
    }); }
```

If you run the flake after commenting every python package above docarray, you get this error when running the flake:

error:

```
   … while calling the 'derivationStrict' builtin

     at /builtin/derivation.nix:9:12: (source not available)

   … while evaluating derivation 'nix-shell'
     whose name attribute is located at /nix/store/zaza7mgggz4m5h6z18kajabf4wciaj47-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:331:7

   … while evaluating attribute 'buildInputs' of derivation 'nix-shell'

     at /nix/store/zaza7mgggz4m5h6z18kajabf4wciaj47-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:378:7:

      377|       depsHostHost                = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 1) 0;
      378|       buildInputs                 = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 1) 1;
         |       ^
      379|       depsTargetTarget            = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 2) 0;

   (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)

   error: undefined variable 'jina'

   at /nix/store/9z9khfrsm3dx1jh55cw09zi36l6dg1q2-source/flake.nix:162:13:

      161|             vectordb
      162|             jina # Include jina in the environment
         |             ^
      163|             jcloud # Include jcloud in the environment
```

It means you have to install jcloud. uncomment jcloud. the error message say you have to install another package. Therefore you uncomment more until you uncomment the jina-hubble-sdk package. And you get this error

> error: builder for
> '/nix/store/c4xggnbjhl6wj6w71c6nszzxx39iv93a-python3.11-jina-3.24.0.drv'
> failed with exit code 1;
> last 10 log lines:
> >   ir_d = dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.install_requires)
> > WARNING: The directory '/homeless-shelter/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user.
> The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that
> directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
> > WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7ffff55a3cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/docarray/
> > WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7ffff55b07d0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/docarray/
> > WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7ffff55b1310>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/docarray/
> > WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7ffff55b1e10>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/docarray/
> > WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7ffff55b2990>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/docarray/
> > ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docarray>=0.16.4 (from versions: none)
> > ERROR: No matching distribution found for docarray>=0.16.4
> > error: Command '['/nix/store/3v2ch16fkl50i85n05h5ckss8pxx6836-python3-3.11.8/bin/python3.11',
> '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps',
> '-w', '/build/tmp0nl2c1kv', '--quiet', 'docarray>=0.16.4']' returned
> non-zero exit status 1.
> For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/c4xggnbjhl6wj6w71c6nszzxx39iv93a-python3.11-jina-3.24.0.drv'.
> error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/gw13rrga3q9mfsyly7lksmqpz85b81gd-python3-3.11.8-env.drv'
> failed to build error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/81jdcd1la69iry4f83cgwhim27gvnvsb-nix-shell-env.drv' failed
> to build

It means that you have to install docarray. How can solve this circular dependency problem